# python - to extract a specific string

Tags: python

I have a string like :

```
    string="(tag, index: develop-AB123-2s), (index: develop-CD123-2s)"
```

I want to extract only "develop-CD123-2s", i.e. the string that comes after "(index:" and not the one with tag. How do I do in python? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Warning: I'm not the best at regex</sup>

```
import re
s='(tag, index: develop-AB123-2s), (index: develop-CD123-2s)'
print re.findall("\\(.*?index: ([^)]+)", s)[1]  # 'develop-CD123-2s'
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zF786N/1)

Alternative regex

```
re.findall("index: ([^\s)]+)", s)[1]
```

Comment: Always useful to use `r"..."` style strings with regex to avoid needing to use double slashes.

Comment: I know. Just a Java habit. Also don't need the `(.*?`, really.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> string.split("), (")[1].split(":")[1].split(")")[0].strip()
'develop-CD123-2s'
>>>
```

The first split separates each tuple, then split on : and take the second result

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
string = "(tag, index: develop-AB123-2s), (index: develop-CD123-2s)"

string = string.split('(index:')
string = string[1].strip(')')
print(string)
```

split the string on `(index:` and strip off the closing curly bracket

Answer (score 1):

One way is using python regex - [positive lookbehind assertion](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

```
import re
string = "(tag, index: develop-AB123-2s), (index: develop-CD123-2s)"
re.findall(r"(?<=\(index:) ([^)]+)", string)
```

This pattern only matches things that start with `(index:`. You can also look at negative lookbehind assertions to try and match the `(tag,` part.